# How can I change the image that is shown when user hovers over published actions from my facebook app?

Tags: image, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

When I publish an action from my facebook open graph app I can set the picture that will show on news feeds and on the timeline, but when I hover over the story in the timelone I am still seeing the default open graph icon (this one) - [image]

I use the javascript SDK to publish activities from my app like this -

```
FB.api(
    '/me/{MNAMESPACE{:{ACTION}?{OBJECT}={URL}&image=PATH_TO_IMAGE,
    'post'
    );
```

I've tried sending more than one image  as the image field in the actions properties is an array so have used this -

```
FB.api(
'/me/{MNAMESPACE{:{ACTION}?{OBJECT}={URL}&image=PATH_TO_IMAGE1,PATH_TO_IMAGE2,
'post'
);
```

but that still does not work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image on your object not your action.